# C# How to: Comparing two string values ( 1 user input, 1 pre-set)

Tags: c#, .net

***Basic Outline:***
I'm currently trying to write a simple program that allows the "User" to "Input" a password into the console, "Their Input" is then checked against the "Pre-Set" Correct Password.

- If the Password is Correct (Displays Correct Message)
- If the Password is Wrong (Displays Incorrect Message)

Error: I know what the problem is:
On Line 12, I have not compared the "Users" Input to the "Pre-Set" Password. But after doing some research I wasn't able to find the code where I could compare these two strings.
Due to this Error, the "Incorrect Password" on Line 9, won't display.

Any Ideas on how I could compare?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string correctpassword = "michael";
        string userinputpassword = "";
        bool validpassword = false;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your password:");
            try
            {
                correctpassword = (Console.ReadLine());
                if (userinputpassword == correctpassword)
                    validpassword = true;
                else
                    validpassword = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password");
            }
        } while (!validpassword);

        Console.WriteLine("Login Successful, Your password is:" + correctpassword);
    } //End Main
```

Comment: try to put you correctpassword= Console.Readline(); outside of your try catch like this `Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your password:");
  correctpassword = (Console.ReadLine()); try.....`

Comment: @kulotskie Thank you for your Input, Unfortunately the Same Problem's Occur. The Program Loops back to "Please Enter your Password:" without Displaying "Correct or Incorrect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, the line `Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password");` will only execute if an exception is thrown in your try block.  You don't throw any exceptions when the password doesn't match, so it doesn't get executed.  You *could* throw choose to throw an exception if the passwords don't match, and then this code would work (sorta).  But, this is bad design.  A user entering a wrong password is a normal and expected error, not an exceptional error (see [Eric's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) about when exceptions are appropriate).  So, it's better to simply add the line to your else block instead.

Also, you have a typo in your code on the line where you read the user's input.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string correctpassword = "michael";
        string userinputpassword = "";
        bool validpassword = false;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your password:");
            userinputpassword = (Console.ReadLine()); //typo here
            if (userinputpassword == correctpassword) {
                validpassword = true;
            } else {
                validpassword = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password");
            }
        } while (!validpassword);

        Console.WriteLine("Login Successful, Your password is:" + correctpassword);
    } //End Main
```

That being said, please be aware that this is NOT how a program should normally authenticate a user.  What you're doing is fine for a toy program you're learning with, which this appears to be, but in a production system, a user's password should never be stored at all.  Instead, you use hashes to determine if the user's password is correct.

Comment: Thank you for Pointing out the Typo for me. Regarding to the Authentication, as you said this is just a toy program to get the basic idea of how to use different statements. With the Throw, I will talk more about it in the Comment I'm Leaving on "StillLearnin".  This comment also applies to you. Again Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try running with a debugger, that way you can see what the value of each variable is, and check this matches your expectations.

When things go wrong you can also log the relevant variables. e.g.

```
try
{
  correctpassword = (Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("UserInput: {0}", userinputpassword));
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("correctpassword: {0}", correctpassword));
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("passwords match: {0}", correctpassword == userinputpassword));

  if (userinputpassword == correctpassword)
    ...
```

If you run your code with those logging statments you should see the problem. `correctPassword` should always be "michael" but it will be what the user enters. `userinputpassword` should be what the user entered but is always empty.

You are setting the users input to the variable `correctPassword`

```
correctpassword = (Console.ReadLine());
```

You should be assigning this to `userinputpassword`

```
userinputpassword = (Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this Typo out to me, regarding to the "Logging Statements" they were very helpful(Pointing out the missing Section) and I am sure in later codes I will be using them again.                                            Within the Logging Statements:-   correctpassword: (Is Blank)

Answer (score 0):

Your `try`/`catch` is akin to sticking wings on a block of wood. In your mind it might turn into a graceful swan flying everywhere, but in real life it's still just a block of wood that sits there and.. well.. blocks. Only with wings. People will give you confused looks.

What you want is trivially written as:

```
while(true) 
{
  Console.Write("Password: ");
  var pw=Console.ReadLine();

  if(pw==correctpw)
    break;
  else 
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect password.");
}
```

No `try`/`catch` required. This isn't Java, in C# we use exceptions for exceptional code. Fancy that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I did try your path-way and it didn't work that well for me. But I did use the "var" idea form your code and now my code works fine. Thank you for our feedback.

Comment: "Didn't work that well" I beg to differ: https://ideone.com/mE59CU Perhaps you should scrap the whole thing and crack open a basic book on programming. Somehow you're failing to run already completely written code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend you. I was saying that your code didn't work for me, but I am sure it does work. The way I was placing it into Visual Must have been different then the way it was intended. Sorry to Upset. But in the end, you gave me the idea for "Var", so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Everyone who Submitted an answer to my question. All your Answer's helped to finish and correct my code.

**Here is the final Result**(*Fully Working*):

```
string correctpassword = "michael";
bool validpassword = false;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your Password: ");
    var userinputpassword = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userinputpassword == correctpassword)
        validpassword = true;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password.");
} while (!validpassword);
Console.WriteLine("Login Successful, Your password is: " + correctpassword );
```

If you have any comments feel free to post here or message me.